# Matplotlib plots not showing up in Mac OSX?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, plot

I am running Mac OSX 10.5.8. I installed matplotlib using macports. I get some examples from the matplotlib gallery like this one, without modification:

http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/unicode_minus.html

I run it, get no error, but the picture does not show up. In Linux Ubuntu I get it.

Do you know what could be wrong here?

Comment: In my case, plot was showing initially then stopped as I was installing couple of other packages like pandasql, boxsdk etc[not sure, what broke it]. Re-installing `matplotliib` resolved my issue. Lot of good suggestions/fixes can be found at the answers. If none of the them helps, before give up, try re-install matplotlib.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I can verify this on my end as well. To fix, here's what I did

```
sudo port install py25-matplotlib +cairo+gtk2
sudo port install py26-matplotlib +cairo+gtk2
```

Also, we need to change the default backend to a GUI based one.

Edit the file `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`, and add:

```
backend: GTKCairo
```

---

Also, you can try the following, which may allow you to not need the GTK or Cairo backends.
Edit `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` and add:

```
backend: MacOSX
```

With the port with those variants installed, this works as well, but it doesn't require X11.

---

By the way, the error that I saw was the following:

```
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py:41: UserWarning: 
Your currently selected backend, 'Agg' does not support show().
Please select a GUI backend in your matplotlibrc file ('/Users/wlynch/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc') or with matplotlib.use()
(backend, matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()))
```

Comment: Which did you end up using? the MacOSX backend or the GTKCairo one?

Comment: I had to add the file matplotlibrc b\c it wasn't there. I used the MacOSX backend successfully.

Answer (score 159):

I had the same problem, even I could see how a new application window was created and immediately disappeared.

Simple solution - just check if you have

```
# Assumes you have imported "matplotlib.pyplot" as "plt"
plt.show()
```

after the plot

Comment: This worked for me with the same problem on `pylab`. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me also using pandas plot and then`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and then let it show up. It's a bit strange but it worked fine!

Comment: This was the solution to getting plots showing in PyCharm 2018.1 (running on OSX) in the Scientific mode tab (SciView) as well!

Comment: The reason this works is to do with interactive vs non-interactive mode. If the backend is opened in non-interactive mode, `plt.show()` is required at the end of the code chunk. You can check the status by calling `plt.isinteractive()` and toggle the status using `plt.ion()` and `plt.ioff()`

Comment: Don't do as I did; confuse `fig.show()` with `plt.show()`.

Comment: @Ninad P you should post your comment as an answer!

Answer (score 50):

This is what worked for me. I just changed the import of Matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: this also worked for me on mac OS X inside a virtual environment

Comment: Also worked for me! The `pyplot` should be imported after the `.use`!

Comment: I've set `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")` after all the imports, and it still works fine, so I don't think the order is important here.

Comment: A correction to my previous comment - in works like this with the latest matplotlib versions, but in older versions you indeed had to do that before importing.

Answer (score 13):

When you try

```
plt.savefig('myfilename.png')
```

instead of

```
plt.show()
```

does that save the correct image named `myfilename.png` in the current path?

Comment: Also: this suggests (for the 'not showing up' part) that you may need to have a matplotlibrc file (search for it first) and change the backend to tkAgg: http://newmediaandcapitalmarkets.org/component/content/article/68-how-i-got-matplotlib-working-on-my-macbook.html . Which python are you using?

Answer (score 7):

After the plot simply add -

`plt.show()`

The reason this works is to do with interactive vs non-interactive mode. If the backend is opened in non-interactive mode, `plt.show()` is required at the end of the code chunk. You can check the status by calling `plt.isinteractive()` and toggle the status using `plt.ion()` and `plt.ioff()`

Comment: @nphadke - Using `plt.show()` - I got my plot to show , then I tried before my `plt.legend()`, I did `plt.ion()` - and removed `plt.show()`, and I got my `plt.isinteractive()` to print `True`, but still I didn't get my plot to show. So, where should one do `plt.ion()` to switch to interactive mode - if somebody just wanted to check if this works or not without using `plt.show()`?

Answer (score 4):

I wanna share this workable solution for me,

```
import matplotlib
import platform
if platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
```

Answer (score 3):

just to add a note,

The matplotlibrc file was not present on my system and I had to to download a copy from the matplotlib website. Future users may have to do the same.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
brew install pkg-config
brew link pkg-config
brew install pygtk
brew install freetype
brew install libpng

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/freetype/*/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/freetype2.pc

git clone git@github.com:matplotlib/matplotlib.git
cd matplotlib
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

References:

http://blog.caoyuan.me/2012/08/matplotlib-error-mac-os-x/
http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html#install-from-git
http://www.tapir.caltech.edu/~dtsang/python.html

Comment: this in combination with putting `backend: tkAgg` in ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I only had python 2.5 and I did not want to install python 2.6 on my mac. So I used different procedure mentioned in the following link to solve this problem:

http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=54928

**What that one actually needs is the following steps:**

1) Searching where is the directory "pygtk-2.0.pc" and locate it. For example mine was located in the following directory:

/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig

2) Adding the path information to envirement variable. For example:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

3) Download the configuration information file "matplotlibrc" from matplotlib website
  http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/_static/matplotlibrc

4) Change backend to MacOSX in the file and save it

5) Copy the file to directory .matplotlib
   You can locate the directory in python by the following command:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_configdir()
```

Answer (score 2):

Mac comes with its own Python.  More details can be found [in the Matplotlib FAQ](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/installing/index.html#osx-notes), but it's not the best explanation.

I would suggest just a clean install of some Python 3.7 or so along with Anaconda and then introduce them as interpreters to PyCharm. Anything will work fine and you wont need to add ad-hoc solutions like `backend: MacOSX` or so.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo port install py37-matplotlib +cairo+gtk3
~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc used 
backend: MacOSX
```

Seemed to work on MacOS Mojave 10.14.4 with python 3.7 on the [unicode_minus.py example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/unicode_minus.html) above.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following if anyone is using spyder.

1.) Start Spyder 2.3.5.2 from Anaconda Launcher
2.) Go to preferences -> IPython console -> Graphics -> Backend: changed it to "Automatic"
3.) Select "Apply" and close preferences
3.) Restart IPython kernel
4.) Create simple graphic like

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary work around one can save the figure to a .png/.jpg/.pdf and make use of that file for the moment.

```
## assuming price is out DataFrame that contains columns that we want to plot 
pdf_plot=price.plot().get_figure()  
pdf_plot.savefig('Stocks.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

conda
The default python provided in (Ana)conda is not a framework build. However, a framework build can easily be installed, both in the main environment and in conda envs: install python.app (conda install python.app) and use pythonw rather than python.