# Embedding matplotlib in Python GTK3 on Rpi

Tags: python, matplotlib, raspberry-pi, gtk3

I've encountered a problem with embedding matplotlib in a GTK3 window on Raspberry Pi. The program runs, returns no error but the plots/figures don't show/render. It's very similar to this question : [Matplotlib not showing up in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512225/matplotlib-not-showing-up-in-mac-osx)

Unmodified Matplotlib example:  http://matplotlib.or.g/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk3.html
returns a blank scroll window, with an empty canvas of set size (800x600).
Matplotlib configuration directory is : */home/pi/.config/matplotlib* ,
as pointed by:

```
matplotlib.get_configdir() .
```

In that directory there is a matplotlibrc file. Which contains the following:

```
backend : GTK3Agg
backend_fallback : True
figure.figsize : 5.5, 4.5
savefig.dpi : 80
docstring.hardcopy : True
```

I have tried different configurations, the end result remains the same, nothing renders.

I have tried to force matplotlib to use GTK3Agg as default renderer by 
stating :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('GTK3Agg') # also tried matplotlib.use(u'GTK3Agg')
```

Nothing. I'm really puzzled because the mentioned example and my own code works flawlessly on Windows machines, each with different GTK and matplolib versions.

I'm using :

- Rpi OS version : Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+
- GTK (from repository) : 3.10.2
- Matplotlib (built) : 1.5.dev1
- Python: 2.7.3

Matplotlib version on repository is 1.1.x, but I require at least 1.2.x for my project. 
Thank you in advance!