# Matplotlib pyplot.show() get stuck in ipython notebook on Mac

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, anaconda

I wanted to draw a plot using `matplotlib.pyplot`, but the ipython notebook got stuck when the `plt.show()` is called. 
The function works well in terminal and I can save the image using `plt.savefig()` function in ipython notebook as well.

I'm working on Mac OS X El Capitan and python 3.5.2 and matplotlib 1.5.1 both installed by anaconda.
Following was my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
plt.show()
```

I have looked this question [Matplotlib not showing up in Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512225/matplotlib-not-showing-up-in-mac-osx) and tried adding the following into `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`(the file didn't exist, I created it by vim). It didn't help.

```
backend:MacOSX
```

Have any one encountered this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try running `%matplotlib`.  This looks like issues with integrating the event loop.

Comment: That can help. Thanks a lot! By the way, I added `%matplotlib inline` and the image can display within the page.