# Matplotlib doesn't show plots on Mac; plt.show() hangs on 'MacOSX' backend

Tags: python, matplotlib, backend, freeze

As of late, I can't get my Matplotlib plots to show up. I have a *very* simple script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
```

but nothing ever shows up. If I include the line

```
plt.show()
```

then my Python process hangs.

In my `~/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` file I have

```
backend      : MacOSX
interactive  : True
```

I'm a little embarrassed to ask this question. I've been a Matplotlib user for many years and have never had this problem. I don't know where to begin to fix this problem. **Help!**

I'm using Matplotlib 2.0.0 with Python 3.5.2 from Anaconda.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matplotlib not showing up in Mac OSX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512225/matplotlib-not-showing-up-in-mac-osx)

Comment: You could try another backend first, `import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("backend")` where `"backend"` could be `"Qt4Agg", "Qt5Agg", "Tkagg"` or even `"Agg"` (just for saving images).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Well, that worked; I used the `"Qt5Agg"` backend. I guess this points to a problem with my `"MacOSX"` backend? Is that no longer supported in matplotlib 2.0.0?

Comment: No, of course MacOSX backend should work as well. It's just that now you found out that its a MacOSX backend problem, and have found a workaround for the moment. I have never worked with Apple products in my life, but other people may have an idea about a possible solution.

Comment: @RobertValencia: this is the same symptom as [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512225/matplotlib-not-showing-up-in-mac-osx) but different cause, there are many possible causes on MacOS alone (installation, backend, config, not having explicit `plt.show()`), so what should we do, merge this or let it stand?

Comment: @smci sorry for the delayed response. If it's the same symptom, but of a different cause, I guess it should stand as an independent question. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer, as pointed out by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest is that the backend configuration for me wasn't working. I'm not sure if I need to install some additional libraries or not. I decided not to use the `MacOSX` backend and used the `Qt5Agg` backend. This worked just fine and I didn't have to install any new libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I've just remove the line

```
interactive: True
```

enter code here

from my `~/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`. It works fine with only `backend: MacOSX` using the `plt.show()` command.